# Reverse leftover

Tags: java

I am working on a program that reads a string of characters and reverses certain characters based off a number.
(i.e. "TELLER" and 3 is given, it should return "LETREL)
The problem I am running into is that I need to reverse the extra characters left over
(i.e. "HELLO" and 3 is given, it returns "LEHLO" when I need it to return "LEHOL")
This is how i'm currently trying to go about it

```
for (int i = 0; i < st.length();) {
            if (i + x > st.length()-1){
                break;
            }

            st = st.substring(0, i) + new String(new StringBuilder(st.substring(i, i + x)).reverse()) + st.substring(i + x);

            i += x; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String input = "Hello";
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
int x = 3;

for(int d = 0; d < Math.floor(input.length / x); d++){
    buffer.append((new StringBuilder(input.substring(d * x, (d + 1) * x))).reverse());
}

if(input.length % x != 0) buffer.append((new StringBuilder(input.substring(input.length - input.length % x - 1))).reverse());

System.out.println("Result is " + buffer.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This worked but there was an added letter at the end for some reason.. I gave the input STOPLIGHT 7 and it returned GILPOTSTHG instead of GILPOTSTH

Comment: Remove '-1' here
if(input.length % x != 0) buffer.append((new StringBuilder(input.substring(input.length - input.length % x - 1))).reverse());

Comment: Ah yep, removing the -1 seems to have fixed it. Thank you again for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It should work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < st.length();) {
        if (i + x > st.length()-1){
            s += new String(new StringBuilder(st.substring(i, st.length())).reverse());
            break;
        }

        s += new String(new StringBuilder(st.substring(i, i + x)).reverse());

        i += x;
    }
```

Let me know if you don't understand any part. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That didnt seem to work though, It is now looping infinitely and not even returning anything.

Comment: I have checked the code, it worked. can you please tell me your sample input. I have tried st = "HELLO" and x = 3.

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation, + and +=, is expensive as several String-s are created.
Also it would be easier to step through the string in the given step size:

```
StringBuilder reversed = new StringBuilder(st.length);
for (int i = 0; i + x <= st.length(); i += x) {
    int nextI = Math.min(i + x, st.length());
    for (int j = i; j < nextI; ++j) {
        reversed.insert(i, st.charAt(j));
    }
}
s = reversed.toString();
```

Or

```
for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); ) {
    int nextI = Math.min(i + x, st.length());
    for (int j = i; j < nextI; ++j) {
        reversed.insert(i, st.charAt(j));
    }
    i = nextI;
}
```